# Odoo V13 Custom fields in product menu don't show up

Tags: python, xml, field, product, odoo-13

I'm trying to add a simple custom field to the product menu but it doesn't appear.

My modifications in the product models are visible in the "technical>models" menu and my view is well loaded in the views list, there's no error or warning.

models/product.py

```
from odoo import fields, models

class Product(models.Model) :
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    test = fields.Boolean('Material')
```

models/**init**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import models
from . import material
from . import machine
from . import product
```

view/product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_cbd_product" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">cbd.product</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="sale_ok" position="after">
                <field name="test"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

in the **manifest**.py

```
    'data': [
        'views/product.xml'
    ],
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In developer mode press the bug
2. Click on edit view form
3. Check on inherited view tab to see if your view is there.

Comment: Indeed I was inheriting the wrong view (the good one is product.product_template_only_form_view"). I changed the inherited in my model too from "product.product" to "product.template" but now I have an error "taxes_id field doesn't exists". I check in product.template model and my field is in it. And when I add manually the "taxes_id" field to my inherited model I don't get an error for  this field anymore.

Comment: EDIT: I dropped the database and by field is working, thanks for your help!